# Unable to Connect On-Prem Data Store in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am not able to connect to the on-premises data store in Azure Machine Learning Studio.

Although configured with the Integration Runtime on the on-premises server, while connecting to the on-prem SQL Server Data Store it is giving an error:

> Data Store `<Data_Store_Name>` cannot be reached, Check the connecting
>   settings for the data store.

[image]

Can anyone please help to resolve the issue?

Comment: Is your database accessible "from the outside"? By the way, using `sa` user is not a good practice...

Comment: Yes @NicolasR my database is accessible from outside. sa user I have used just for testing purpose.